# What is the best way to return items in Python that meet a specific condition

Tags: python

The code I'm currently using is:

```
def f(*args):
    lst=[str(i) for i in args]
    if len(lst)==1:lst = lst[0]
    return lst
```

What I would like is:

```
a=f(1) #'1', not [1]

a,b = f(1,2) #'1', '2'
```

Only one argument would be a list, which would be represented by `a`.

What alternative exists aside from using an `if` statement?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: I would **not** special-case this, because "special cases aren't special enough". It is trivial to handle the one-argument case *on the caller's side*: `a, = f(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
return lst[0] if len(lst) == 1 else lst
```

Comment: This isn't really "without an if condition", although it moves the if into an expression.

Comment: On my first read I just thought he was looking for a more compact expression. Having read it again, I think the meaning is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 1):

Returning different types like that can be confusing. I'd recommend using

```
a = f(1)[0]
```

or

```
[a] = f(1)
```

or

```
a, = f(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, no.  If you accept variable arguments with `*args`, then you get a list, even if there is only one argument.

You could of course separate the first argument with `def f(first, *rest)`, but then you have to do special-casing to combine the elements when you *do* want a list.

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking: he's talking about the returned value rather than the arguments.

Comment: Yes, but the reason the question arises is because he's accepting variable arguments.  If he weren't, he would always know whether he was getting one argument or more than one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use yield:

```
def f(*args):
    for i in args:
        yield str(i)

a, = f(1)
print a
a, b = f(1, 2)
print a, b
```

which returns:

```
1
1 2
```

is it what you want?

Comment: The use of `yield` is a complete red herring here. The trick is that you've unpacked a tuple at the call site (`a, = f(1)`) in the one-argument case.

Comment: Karl, I don't think so. Technically i agree with you the yield here is a red herring, but in this case, i suggest to return an integrator as it's more straightforward than return a list. a,=f(1) is not tricky here because his code seems telling us the caller knows how many items will be returned.